# Is there some way to develop Phonegap App in general WWW folder if Android specific XML config files are required?

Tags: android, cordova, connection

I am developing my cordova/phonegap project in GENERAL WWW folder (not in those subfolders who are available under platform folders)

In my application I am checking connection status (if device is online/offline), but there are some configuration changes that are required in (app/AndroidManifest.xml) and also (app/res/xml/config.xml) file. But this files is available just under platform folders.

Is there some workaround for this? (so that I can continue to develop my app in General WWW folder)? And if there is, where should I copy /store these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Command line interface CLI / command prompt to install plugin, then you don't need to worry about any configuration, just install connection plugin and put your code in general WWW.

If you are manually installing plugins, then make changes in `app/AndroidManifest.xml` and `app/res/xml/config.xml` from subfolders as you required, and put your html,js,css files in general WWW folder. when you build a platform or run it, your files from general WWW are put into subfolders' WWW automatically.